# Firefox seems to beautify HTML?

Tags: python, firefox, urllib

I am trying to make a small crawler app.
So I am constantly looking into the code of page inside of Firefox and I download the same page using `urllib` inside of python.

Sample URL: https://store.steampowered.com/search/?term=arma 3

And I checked using two separate libraries of python. Same result. File saved by python app looks different when saved on PC from one saved with browser.

Is it browser making the code more readable or server treats differently than standard browser application in a different way?

Thanks!

I tried saving using 2 different python libraries for accessing the web page.

I won't show the code here, because it's 200K of HTML without new lines.

The HTML code is with new lines when downloading page using normal browser.

Comment: Are you looking at the source code or at the DOM?

Comment: When you use the `Save As` function in the browser, it generates HTML from the DOM, it's not saving the original source code. This results in a canonicalized form of the HTML, and also includes changes to the DOM that were made by JavaScript.

Comment: thank you for insight. makes me think.